# Handling WASD and Arrows simultaneously in JavaScript game

Tags: javascript

Let's assume the simple pong game for two players with one keyboard.

The movement handler appears to be easy:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 87) { //w
            movePaddle(leftPaddle, 0);

        } else if (event.keyCode === 83) { //s
            movePaddle(leftPaddle, 1);

        } else if (event.keyCode === 38) { //arrow_up
            movePaddle(rightPaddle, 0);

        } else if (event.keyCode === 40) { //arrow_down
            movePaddle(rightPaddle, 1);

        }
});
```

The second argument in `movePaddle` function just means the direction (up or down).

The problem: if `W` and `Up Arrow` are pressed together, then only one paddle moves. It depends on which key were pressed last.

How to handle keydown events correctly?

I need two paddles moving together according pressed keys. If `W` and `Up Arrow`, then both go up. If `W` and `Down Arrow`, then left goes up and right goes down. Of course, only one paddle should move if only one key are pressed.

Comment: you can't move the paddle in the event, you need to move it constantly in a "game loop". onkeydown, you set a state, `isMoving=true`, for each paddle. in the game loop,  `if(isMoving)` then move the paddle. onkeyup, set `isMoving=false`. that's the only way to do this because keyboards can't fire repeated "typematic" events on more than one key at a time.

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/RepComm/52690eadaa9f4a3e7a7819b3267feca4

Use it like this: (In a loop of any kind, this one just uses anim frame)

```
Input.init();
var test = function () {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(test);
    if (Input.isKeyDown("w")) {
        console.log("Forward March!");
    }
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(test);
```

Comment: Good idea, but it has performance issue because of `Input.keys[keyName]`. In this case browser have to walk through Input.keys array each time. Of course, it's not a problem in a very simple loop, but my game uses heavy liquid dynamics computations, so it is obviously that this solution works more slowly than direct flags as dandavis suggested.

Comment: Ah, I see. Also, the more different keys pressed, the longer it takes walking through the array. If you ever need extensibility though!

Answer (score 0):

Try separating the keys by saying

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 87) { //w
            movePaddle(leftPaddle, 0);

        } else if (event.keyCode === 83) { //s
            movePaddle(leftPaddle, 1);

        }
        // Separate them here
        if (event.keyCode === 38) { //arrow_up
            movePaddle(rightPaddle, 0);

        } else if (event.keyCode === 40) { //arrow_down
            movePaddle(rightPaddle, 1);

        }
});
```

This will work because you're saying else if for every single one, that means that only one of them can be true at the same time.

What I'm saying is that when using else if, the else if is paired to the if, and much like just else, only one of the blocks can be true at the same time